# Does SQL server developer edition have a gui?

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, macos, user-interface

I have installed Microsoft sql server developer edition on my mac using docker and understand I have full functionality through terminal. But I was wondering if the installation on a windows machine comes with any sort of a GUI?

If not, what are the more common(free) GUI/tools for managing MS SQL Server? On both MacOS and Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: You could have searched yourself, but have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5f600bdd-3a3b-4c81-b4d5-b8ba1ac61745/sql-server-management-studio-for-mac?forum=sqltools)

Answer (score 6):

The most common GUI for SQL Server on windows is [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) which is **free**. That is based on Visual Studio Shell so it's not available for other platforms.

But [SQL Operations Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio) is a new free, opensource, cross-platform GUI you can use on your mac.

> SQL Operations Studio is a data management tool that enables you to
>   work with SQL Server, Azure SQL DB and SQL DW from Windows, macOS and
>   Linux.

Another cross-platform one is [SQLECTRON](https://sqlectron.github.io/), which is also free and opensource. also you can use this for working with multiple databases:

> Current supported databases:
>   PostgreSQL
>   MySQL
>   Microsoft SQL Server
>   Cassandra (NoSQL; Exceptions about this client)
>   SQLite